# jQuery: How to trigger "e" in function(e) { ... }?

Tags: jquery

I have one master text field, and I want it so that when the user types into this text field that the text fields with class `variant_price` get updated with the same text.

I have it almost done:

```
$("#master_price").keypress(function (e) {
    $(".variant_price").val($(this).val());
});
```

However, on the first keypress, it seems to fire off the `$(".variant_price").val($(this).val());` part before `e` happens, so when I type `123` the `variant_price` text fields only get updated with `23` without the first keypress (`1`).

How would I trigger e before that line? Is there anything like `e.fire()`?

Comment: `e` doesn't *happen*. It's an object describing what has happened or is happening, i.e. the `keypress`.

Comment: How would I delay `$(".variant_price").val($(this).val());` until after the keypress is fired?

Comment: You can listen for `keyup` either as well or instead of `keypress`. By the time that event occurs, the `value` will have been modified. The delay you're seeing is because the default action of the `keypress` event, which occurs after all of its handlers, is what modifies the `value`. So, `keypress` is your chance to *cancel* the modification via `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the use case you've described, you are looking for the [`change` event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) rather than `keypress` (A field can be modified by pasting via mouse button, for example).

Also, you don't need the event object (`e`) at all.

```
$("#master_price").change(function() {
    $(".variant_price").val($("#master_price").val());
});
```

If you want an *instant* reaction to a change, you may bind the same *handler to multiple events* without storing the function as a temporary, as follows:

```
$("#master_price").on("change keyup", function() {
    $(".variant_price").val($("#master_price").val());
})
```

Comment: Nice. One note is that this would require a mouseclick outside of the text field for everything to update though. I did some research and I think this plus `keyup` is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `keypress` you should use `keyup` that should do the trick or `change` as suggested:

```
$("#master_price").keyup(function(e) {
    $(".variant_price").val($(this).val());
});
```

Because `keypress` is triggered when the key is down and `keyup` when its up again.